# Why I am getting error getting string from List<Map<String,Object>> in Text getting error String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

[getting error parsing List<Map<String,Object>>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTRDS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like below line;

```dart
return Text(question[0]["questionsText"] ?? '');
```

Also, why reason for getting this error, "Dart Null-Safety". You should check dart null-safety documentation.

https://dart.dev/null-safety